# Make Score Value to evaluate social popularity (from fb likes count)

Tags: rating

I have a list of websites and Facebook likes count for each of them.
Count varies from 0 to millions.

For each website I want to make up some Score Value from 0 to 10, which would represent sites' social popularity.

Any thoughts how to deal with such a problem would be much appreciated.

**Update:**
Data summary:
 Min.   :       1
 1st Qu.:       2
 Median :       8
 Mean   :     908
 3rd Qu.:      28
 Max.   :10841643

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this would work: $$ \text{social popularity} = \frac{\text{count}}{\text{max count}} \cdot 10$$

Comment: +1 I would suggest perhaps taking the log of the count (+1), because this kind of data will have an extreme right tail. Unless you do some kind of transform, you'll end up with the vast bulk of sites having a score of 0 or 1, and a handful with 9 or 10.

Comment: It is indeed extremely right tailed. 
Min.   :       1  
1st Qu.:       2  
Median :       8  
Mean   :     908  
3rd Qu.:      28  
Max.   :10841643
Can you please write exact formula, where that log(count) should go. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for @HongOoi suggestion. Usually this type of web counters follows a Zipf curve, which, when is plotted as $x = log(rank+1)$ over $y = log(count+1)$ looks linear. Also, it depends on what you want to achieve with that score.

Comment: The skewness of the distribution is a fundamental feature of this kind of data, I disagree on using any log transformation. (+1) to snegostup's comment and (+1) to PEV's answer.